# JSON Path: get first children in an object

Tags: json, jsonpath

Got an API response looking like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "unpredictable_name_1": {
      "inner_data": [
        {
          "wanted_data": "something1",
          "other_data": 1000
        },
        {
          "wanted_data": "something2",
          "other_data": 1001
        }
      ],
      "something_else_1": "some_data"
    },
    "unpredictable_name_2": {
      "inner_data": [
        {
          "wanted_data": "something1",
          "other_data": 1000
        },
        {
          "wanted_data": "something2",
          "other_data": 1001
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need a JSON path query returning only this:

```json
[
  {
    "wanted_data": "something1",
    "other_data": 1000
  },
  {
    "wanted_data": "something2",
    "other_data": 1001
  }
]
```

If use this `$..inner_data`, I got both inner_data arrays, and I found no way to get only the first one. (Tested here: https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/). `$..inner_data[0]` does not work as it gives me twice the same array element from both objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ...

```
$.data.unpredictable_name_1.inner_data
```

... will return:

```
[
   {
      "wanted_data" : "something1",
      "other_data" : 1000
   },
   {
      "wanted_data" : "something2",
      "other_data" : 1001
   }
]
```

But I suspect that you deliberately choose the attribute name `unpredictable_name_1` to suggest that you won't know the name of that attribute and hence cannot rely on including that name in your json path.

I think you want to get the entire content of the `inner_data` attribute of the *first* attribute of `data` but since the top level attributes of data are not elements in an array they have no concept of first or second or any position.

To put it another way: `unpredictable_name_1` is only first in your view of the document, JsonPath has no concept of it being the first attribute of `data` therefore JsonPath cannot find that attribute on the basis of position.

By contrast, `inner_data` is an array so it can be addressed by position. For example: `$..inner_data[0]` will return the first element of each of the `inner_data` attributes. JsonPath can apply the positional operator `[0]` because `inner_data` is an array.

So, JsonPath cannot do this: *get the entire content of the `inner_data` attribute of the first attribute of `data`* because the top level attributes in `data` are not members of an array. In order to get that data from the given JSON you would need to deserialise the JSON into some structure (such as a Map) using a JSON library (in the Java realm this would probably be Gson or Jackson, you don't mention your language in the OP but there's likey to a JSON de/serialisation library in whatever language you are using) and you would then apply your own definition of *first* to that structure.